# Calling FindMaximum on a function that only evaluates for numerical arguments

Tags: function-construction

I have a large package of Mathematica routines for magnetic resonance simulations.They work great but there is one problem I just cannot crack. It boils down to the following problem: suppose there is a routine that evaluates to a real numeric value if it has a numerical argument, but to something else if the argument is not numeric. As a demonstration example, consider this function:

```
g[x_?NumericQ] := Cos[x] 
g[x : Except[_?NumericQ]] := $Failed
```

I would expect `FindMaximum` and similar routines to pass a numerical value to the function, so that this behaves just like `Cos`. However, it doesn't work:

```
FindMinimum[g[x], {x, 0.5}]
```

> During evaluation of In[37]:= FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value     $Failed is not a real number at {x} = {0.5}.
>
> ```
> FindMinimum[g[x], {x, 0.5}]
> ```

Of course my real example is much more complicated, but this demonstrates the problem. Why does this behaviour happen, and what can be done to get round it?

Comment: You do not need the second definition that returns $Failed to ensure that the function will only attempt to evaluate on numerical values.. If you remove it, everything works.

Comment: @MarcoB The OP has defined the function in the manner shown to simulate his real life code.

Comment: What can be done: define a new function which does not evaluate for non-numeric arguments. `f[x_?NumericQ] := g[x]`.  If `g[x]` immediately evaluates to `$Failed`, then `FindMinimum` will only see `$Failed`.  The expression passed to `FindMinimum` *must* evaluate to a number after doing an `expr /. x -> number` type replacement on it.  Let me know if you still have questions after this explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The work around is to put a wrapper around your magnetic resonance function which you are emulating with `g[x]`.

```
g[x_?NumericQ] := Cos[x]
g[x : Except[_?NumericQ]] := $Failed
```

Incidentally the reason you are experiencing this problem can be found in the documentation for FindMinimimum

> FindMinimum first localizes the values of all variables, then evaluates f with the variables being symbolic, and then repeatedly evaluates the result numerically.

The new function is:

```
gN[x_?NumericQ] := g[x]
```

and this will work fine.

```
FindMinimum[gN[x], {x, 0.5}]
(* {-1., {x -> 3.14159}} *)
```

Comment: This is, in my opinion, entirely equivalent to removing the `.. Except[` definition in the original definition, only unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: OK, thanks, I get the idea. This definitely gives me something to go on.